# how can i add an id to an image tag using php or jquery if the image source is equal to something specific in url form?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

how can i add an id to a image tag using php or jquery  if the image source is equal to something specific in url form?

i am very new to php and jquery and  i come across and interesting problem i have a website called lingeriesshop.net and im trying to add live chat to the site but the custom live chat image i have selected in my chat plugins console is appearing with 50px of space between the image and the side of my page. the code is being generated from serverside scripts running through the chat service  so i cannot add or remove css classes or id's in a traditional way in order to adjust the image position. i was suggested a solution to use jquery to add a class to the image using this jquery code to add css to the class to move the image 50px

```
$("#imageID").addClass("classname");
```

but the image code i am trying to add a class to does not have an inline #id and im not to familiar with image id's in wordpress in general here is the image code i get from firebug.

```
<img style="white-space: nowrap; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;" src="http://lingeriesshop.net/redchatimage.png">
```

is it possible to write an if statement to where if the image tags src is equal to a set value then add an id to the image tag to later reference the id and add a class to adjust its position? im not a php experienced person so im not sure if this is possible or how to go about it im just trying to move my image over 50px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your img is wrapped in a div or other element, you can reference it in your CSS without a class.

If the html is something like this...

```
<div id='chatwindow'>
  <div id='conversation'>
    ...
  </div>
  <div id='userinput'>
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  <img style="white-space: nowrap; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;" src="http://lingeriesshop.net/redchatimage.png">
</div>
```

Then you can use CSS to move the img 50px to the right...

```
#chatwindow img {margin-left: -10px !important;}
```

Comment: hi thanks for the great reply but the code to the chat is being called with a script 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.mylivechat.com/chatinline.aspx?hccid=30544929"></script>                                                                and i cant find any divs in firebug with a class or even any image tags with a class or id  i might be crashing and burning on this one i tryed the above jquery solutions but so far to no avail all of these answers are great and on point but i think  the inline styles are overpowering my styles

Comment: this is the div with the overpowering css <div style="overflow: hidden; cursor: pointer; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 80px; height: 195px;"><img style="white-space: nowrap; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;" src="http://lingeriesshop.net/redchatimage.png"></div>

Comment: if i add 50px to the left position to this div in firebug the issue is resolved is there a way to overpower generated inline css?

Comment: editing both the div or the image tag with a 50px left position resolves it i just cant overpower there css so far =)

Comment: add !important `#chatwindow img {left: 50px !important;}`

Comment: thanks vlad ill remember that in the future for my hacks but i still got beat lol heres what i tryed to do i added a class and id using jquery with the following code 
$('img[src="redchatimage.png"]').attr('id','chat');
$('chat').addClass('chatimage');
then i used your css trick with the following code         .chatimage {left: 50px !important;}     i cant find any classes or ids to grab onto so i tryed adding an id and class but it still didnt work

Comment: So did it work with the combination of adding the class with jQuery and using !important in the CSS? That's a good solution, too.

Comment: i know it was an awesome solution dead on answer but there chat scripts must not be overridable in some way it didnt work.there chat settings allow me to add a horizontal offset to the floating button which works to adjust the 50px  i can align it but then the problem is the chat window gets cut off by whatever offset i select so if i offset 47px then i cant exit the chat because it chops off the exit x button in the right corner of the window lol =)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('img[src="image.jpg"]').addClass('classname');
```

or

```
$('img[src*="image.jpg"]').addClass('classname'); // this will find every image src containing "image.jpg"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can edit an element's attribute directly using `attr`. You can use this to give the image an ID which you can later use to refer to.

```
$('img[src="image.jpg"]').attr('id','yourIDHere');
$('yourIDHere').addClass('classname');
```

Comment: hi great reply this answered my question but unfortunatly didnt resolve my issue i noticed in my page source that the chat console is implementing the chat with a script reference 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.mylivechat.com/chatinline.aspx?hccid=30544929"></script> so i think adding things to my stylesheets isnt effecting it maybe because the elements are inline css?

Comment: is there a way to overpower the chats generated inline styles using similar methods?

Answer (score 0):

You can access image using it's source , and add attribute and a class like this :

```
 $('img[src="image_path"]').attr('id','sampleID').addClass('classname');
```